# useQuery not executing on subsequent re-renders

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

`apollo-client`'s `useQuery` hook is executing only on first render and not on subsequent re-render.. however I want the `useQuery` API call to be executed every time a certain  props value changes in the component. I tried `skip` option as well, but no luck.

```
const { data: { translatedProductName } = {} } = useQuery(
    getTranslatedProductCopies,
    {
      variables: {
        styleId,
        styleColor,
      },
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    }
  );
```

Comment: If that variable changes, it should totally make a new request and give you new data after that returned. Did you verify that the variables really change?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `refetch` from react-query and place the props in `useEffect` then execute `refetch()` this will refetch the data every time the dependency array change.

Comment: This should really not be necessary. It is a base functionality of `useQuery` to trigger a new query if the variables change.
If OP really has this behavior, they are either doing something wrong elsewhere in their code, or they found a bug in Apollo Client and should open an issue.